# What is the equivalent of apt-key in aptitude?

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

I'm trying to avoid `apt-*` commands and trying to use `aptitude` for all my Debian systems. In my documentations, there is a command written as `sudo apt-key add key.asc`.

How do I convert `apt-key add` into an aptitude command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `aptitude` equivalent to `apt-key`, and there is no need for it.

`apt-key` does the job, and `aptitude` takes that into account smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an alternative to `apt-key` in `aptitude`. You can install the core debian keys like this though:

```
$ sudo aptitude install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring
```